# Low accuracy when converting model SSD MobileNetv1 to tflite in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the `tensorflow` object detection api in `tensorflow 2.4.1.` I have modified the SSD `Mobilenetv1` pretrained model, and I am trying to convert it to `tensorflow` lite. However, I am getting a different output with a considerably lower performance than before.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('saved_model')
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
# #converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
# #converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
# converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,
                                        tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]
images_list= os.listdir("/content/MyDrive/MyDrive/representative_data/")
def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    return np.array(Image.open(path))
def representative_data_gen():
  for i in range(72):
    image=cv2.imread("/content/MyDrive/MyDrive/representative_data/"+images_list[i])
    images = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(image, tf.uint8), 0)
    #print(images)
    images = tf.compat.v1.image.resize_bilinear(images, [640, 640], align_corners=False)
    yield [images]

converter.representative_dataset=representative_data_gen
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Serialize the model
open('model.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)
```

saved_model is the model that I have stored locally. When I try using inferences using the model.tflite file I am getting different values than the original model. On the original model for one image I am getting this output:

```
[[0.24337725 0.6351127  0.38516122 0.7076594 ]
 [0.2673622  0.36415854 0.39408043 0.44303796]
 [0.2854549  0.15576798 0.3912888  0.21461737]
 [0.54561293 0.9263026  0.6120709  0.9571031 ]
 [0.53607523 0.93863803 0.613716   0.9708498 ]
 [0.5300186  0.95096165 0.6101491  0.9829783 ]
 [0.         0.25321186 0.21036099 0.4150495 ]
 [0.97977203 0.94243306 0.999891   0.9985258 ]
 [0.5688855  0.98845106 0.68230766 1.        ]
 [0.26439393 0.         0.3748169  0.0052964 ]
 [0.523868   0.95313215 0.5843951  0.9843085 ]
 [0.5561901  0.9268055  0.6328303  0.9596125 ]
 [0.56333405 0.9297103  0.61194354 0.97363955]
 [0.5242113  0.94434035 0.57968974 0.9733478 ]
 [0.24705899 0.58940554 0.36841512 0.6353431 ]
 [0.6998688  0.95695746 0.935374   0.9985087 ]
 [0.5676778  0.944553   0.61072737 0.989732  ]
 [0.52943265 0.9224371  0.60241354 0.9664552 ]
 [0.29492486 0.5143376  0.33912945 0.54321367]
 [0.35466743 0.38035372 0.39884788 0.43569848]
 [0.29579696 0.         0.34290215 0.00980917]
 [0.52158904 0.9574179  0.6159549  0.99213105]
 [0.272836   0.3718056  0.36658022 0.455931  ]
 [0.8567797  0.99169993 1.         0.9983983 ]
 [0.2602372  0.4269493  0.3221747  0.45679078]
 [0.30840918 0.         0.39378992 0.00409367]
 [0.54609305 0.9337664  0.5939192  0.97229046]
 [0.5369955  0.9213194  0.588888   0.9528671 ]
 [0.55414003 0.9327579  0.6188144  0.9981975 ]
 [0.24911809 0.         0.39413297 0.01658437]
 [0.54612064 0.98965347 0.63472795 1.        ]
 [0.3359316  0.6405184  0.386935   0.69778955]
 [0.28348807 0.         0.33257052 0.00864748]
 [0.55936444 0.93675387 0.63903964 0.9675981 ]
 [0.56318516 0.9523619  0.64057285 0.9842929 ]
 [0.5385444  0.9243466  0.58092284 0.9635858 ]
 [0.5591617  0.9668263  0.6213115  0.99683106]
 [0.526799   0.93967676 0.5644086  0.97707677]
 [0.2894494  0.5127831  0.3259099  0.5462169 ]
 [0.24881686 0.432522   0.3440869  0.4542246 ]
 [0.53722316 0.93652713 0.58082765 0.9754019 ]
 [0.9142558  0.8036172  0.9953465  0.87431747]
 [0.5822151  0.98919743 0.7393905  0.99906236]
 [0.550308   0.9311302  0.6526129  0.9735651 ]
 [0.9681886  0.95588744 0.9971228  0.99962986]
 [0.2510388  0.63873756 0.293042   0.70286167]
 [0.35704705 0.         0.43682608 0.00618043]
 [0.5451097  0.96104217 0.6516574  0.99736154]
 [0.24710357 0.6098395  0.3842827  0.65444416]
 [0.5442216  0.9250356  0.6096328  0.980747  ]
 [0.24251309 0.6482344  0.27971676 0.7081458 ]
 [0.5770702  0.97158587 0.6416947  0.99976385]
 [0.2676804  0.         0.3186664  0.00815568]
 [0.5273864  0.9546605  0.56628644 0.9894375 ]
 [0.54153293 0.9635044  0.6070141  0.99266726]
 [0.28929484 0.15221418 0.33980817 0.21486779]
 [0.51905644 0.8281502  0.56287026 0.8531384 ]
 [0.5725315  0.96221906 0.6105607  0.9990316 ]
 [0.32806867 0.43091613 0.39902395 0.45719367]
 [0.52576494 0.92725724 0.5765526  0.9592081 ]
 [0.5616086  0.9661043  0.6829738  1.        ]
 [0.5533599  0.94553447 0.6016622  0.9873934 ]
 [0.26665998 0.40935722 0.3285365  0.44829842]
 [0.5310731  0.9906043  0.6118139  1.        ]
 [0.34110123 0.6248279  0.38744426 0.6725014 ]
 [0.97393394 0.93869317 0.99925125 0.9814497 ]
 [0.5185562  0.9410181  0.6063331  0.9772024 ]
 [0.57235855 0.97020566 0.7334549  1.        ]
 [0.32493848 0.         0.413765   0.0036816 ]
 [0.52695143 0.9689187  0.58879185 0.9933872 ]
 [0.55055976 0.9458971  0.658028   0.99045086]
 [0.2927954  0.5268235  0.33840135 0.5597528 ]
 [0.9787069  0.9571627  1.         1.        ]
 [0.3356672  0.         0.4292863  0.0049988 ]
 [0.3076461  0.37833217 0.39782172 0.4637287 ]
 [0.568      0.9812284  0.70725244 1.        ]
 [0.5294949  0.92605036 0.5946635  0.98638374]
 [0.28798655 0.5223129  0.32700756 0.56118226]
 [0.98412776 0.92357624 0.999544   0.9758645 ]
 [0.32098186 0.         0.36190385 0.00738669]
 [0.25278595 0.         0.3067849  0.00931515]
 [0.51394624 0.87113017 0.56284195 0.8938641 ]
 [0.22352192 0.57925904 0.36973855 0.6182579 ]
 [0.5131188  0.9547114  0.5616221  0.98266846]
 [0.97893876 0.3624356  0.9991333  0.42952105]
 [0.2654712  0.38837025 0.30062047 0.447562  ]
 [0.2904047  0.80922455 0.34148172 0.83394593]
 [0.00354181 0.98609024 0.09195718 0.9972933 ]
 [0.3118856  0.62980604 0.39645123 0.65791214]
 [0.24747658 0.6742873  0.37653744 0.7318976 ]
 [0.2475342  0.65337795 0.31528282 0.703096  ]
 [0.24661763 0.43916363 0.33284774 0.46883237]
 [0.5544908  0.9149674  0.6185392  0.9745927 ]
 [0.56396806 0.918386   0.6118021  0.9565282 ]
 [0.29127085 0.50906324 0.33064878 0.53714204]
 [0.2144     0.         0.35042924 0.005808  ]
 [0.36967522 0.         0.41315717 0.010372  ]
 [0.25519958 0.414246   0.31013736 0.44864067]
 [0.50648683 0.9921565  0.59263617 1.        ]
 [0.50682306 0.96514183 0.6035181  0.99603957]]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[0.99707234 0.9919825  0.98964745 0.28732723 0.10270327 0.08018646
 0.05177296 0.04935146 0.04088344 0.03827675 0.03675034 0.03669814
 0.03602394 0.03536698 0.03451921 0.03371903 0.03059173 0.02965695
 0.02786072 0.02698742 0.02459854 0.02405082 0.02397973 0.02341228
 0.0230511  0.02214395 0.0220136  0.02189807 0.02145434 0.02136814
 0.02095257 0.02083707 0.020369   0.01975479 0.01961022 0.01947124
 0.01936822 0.0193326  0.01923051 0.0191756  0.01907553 0.01905495
 0.01904101 0.01900733 0.01886942 0.01877986 0.01860638 0.0182397
 0.01818053 0.0178097  0.01772521 0.01766635 0.01741816 0.01731062
 0.01728319 0.01716009 0.01715893 0.01703525 0.01689868 0.01661517
 0.01655028 0.01654574 0.01640137 0.01629853 0.01593319 0.01581809
 0.01569834 0.01559935 0.01559684 0.015499   0.0150541  0.01491728
 0.01487628 0.01473732 0.01454685 0.01452865 0.0145071  0.01448266
 0.01439441 0.01434552 0.01427445 0.0141159  0.01389657 0.01376216
 0.01351939 0.01348546 0.01337216 0.0133338  0.01326786 0.01315651
 0.01309206 0.0130407  0.01296759 0.01295712 0.01287825 0.0127016
 0.01267427 0.01267344 0.01254466 0.01246487]
100
array([[[113, 111, 116],
        [110, 108, 113],
        [ 98,  96, 101],
        ...,
        [ 40,  59, 102],
        [ 72,  98, 157],
        [ 86, 116, 186]],

       [[105, 100, 106],
        [ 99,  97, 100],
        [ 88,  86,  89],
        ...,
        [ 39,  58,  98],
        [ 48,  73, 129],
        [ 79, 109, 173]],

       [[ 96,  92,  93],
        [ 91,  87,  88],
        [ 83,  79,  80],
        ...,
        [ 38,  57,  90],
        [ 31,  57, 105],
        [ 71, 100, 157]],

       ...,

       [[ 85,  83,  88],
        [ 87,  85,  90],
        [ 91,  89,  92],
        ...,
        [ 28,  27,  32],
        [ 28,  27,  32],
        [ 29,  28,  33]],

       [[ 86,  84,  89],
        [ 89,  87,  92],
        [ 92,  90,  95],
        ...,
        [ 29,  28,  33],
        [ 29,  28,  33],
        [ 30,  29,  34]],

       [[ 93,  91,  96],
        [ 96,  94,  99],
        [100,  98, 103],
        ...,
        [ 30,  29,  34],
        [ 30,  29,  34],
        [ 31,  30,  35]]], dtype=uint8)
```

However, with the tflite model I am getting this output:

```
[[[ 0.5304917   0.549833    0.91950834  0.8638777 ]
  [-0.02295769  0.18331468  0.09861814  0.48379225]
  [-0.03266242  0.07500002  0.16733758  0.475     ]
  [-0.00436713  0.3388003   0.03792062  0.5033066 ]
  [ 0.9821089   0.2072595   1.0032529   0.28237888]
  [ 0.9824238   0.46158594  1.0029379   0.53446764]
  [ 0.9228462   0.71543455  1.003768    0.80956554]
  [ 0.04370334  0.97782534  0.09682078  1.0006025 ]
  [ 0.27969962  0.9863208   0.3433848   1.0042033 ]
  [ 0.9614231   0.17667551  1.001884    0.24036069]]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[10.]
[[0.03125    0.01171875 0.01171875 0.00390625 0.00390625 0.00390625
  0.00390625 0.00390625 0.00390625 0.00390625]]
```

When I run this model on netron this what the outputs show:

```
  name: StatefulPartitionedCall:3    
  type: float32    
  quantization: -0.12643077969551086 ≤ q ≤ 1.308648824691772

  name: StatefulPartitionedCall:2
  type: float32
  quantization: 0 ≤ q ≤ 1.1754943508222875e-38
```

These ranges for `quantization` seem very off and I am wondering what I could possibly be doing wrong with the conversion.

```
  name: StatefulPartitionedCall:1
  type: float32
  quantization: 0.0019955039024353027 ≤ q ≤ 0.07411301136016

  name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  type: float32
  quantization: 10 ≤ q ≤ 10
```

Comment: Are you using this guide for converting the model? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md. Note that you need an intermediate step to export a TFLite-friendly model....If you are doing this already, can you check if accuracy is good with the float version (Just don't do anything after setting converter.experimental_new_converter)?